# Good JavaScript engine for animating via Sprite Sheets (not in canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked around a bit for a great JavaScript Sprite Sheet animator lib/engine but couldn't find any good ones so I thought I'd ask around =).

What I'm looking for in the engine is:

1. Animate an image in a non-canvas setting (ex: div via css or img
   tags)
2. Control frame rate/animation speed
3. Flags to loop or to animate
   once etc.

Are there any engines like this out there?  If not I can always make my own but then again, I don't want to re-invent the wheel =].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/) in the past and been successful.  They give you a pretty healthy amount of control over the animation process.  And besides, even if you don't find it useful, I'm sure you may find a good use for it sometime later down the road.

Comment: Only issue with Spritely is that it only supports single rowed SpriteSheets =/.  At least as far as I could find

Comment: Spritely would be awesome in combination with SASS. You wouldn't have to worry about your spritesheet then and single row wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @CalebKester You're absolutely right.  Still to this day I use Spritely, over a year later... that's a long time on the internet!